# NSUndoManager only Undo, not Redo

Tags: ios, objective-c

I write simple undo and redo change background color base on sample code of NSUndoManager.
All things work well with undo action. But with Redo, it not jump to register method for NSUndoManager registed before.
Follow code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
enum color {kWhite = 0, kRed, kOrange, kYellow, kGreen, kCyan, kBlue, kMagenta};
@interface ViewController (){
  enum color kColor;
  NSArray * colorArr;
  NSUndoManager * undoManager;
}
- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)redo:(id)sender;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.]
  kColor = kWhite;
  colorArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor magentaColor], nil];
  undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
  undoManager.levelsOfUndo = 7;

  NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidUndo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification object:self.undoManager];
  [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidRedo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification object:self.undoManager];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {
  [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]
   setcolor:kColor];

    kColor ++;
    if(kColor > kMagenta) kColor = kWhite;

  [self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];
}
-(void) setcolor:(enum color) color{
  kColor = color;
  [self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];
  NSLog(@"zzzz %d", color);
};

- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender {
  [undoManager undo];
}

- (IBAction)redo:(id)sender {
  [undoManager redo];
}

#pragma mark - Undo support

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  undoManagerDidUndo:
//  Handler for the NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification.  Redisplays the table
//  view to reflect the changed value.
//  See also: -setEditing:animated:
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)undoManagerDidUndo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //[self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  undoManagerDidRedo:
//  Handler for the NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification.  Redisplays the table
//  view to reflect the changed value.
//  See also: -setEditing:animated:
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)undoManagerDidRedo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    //[self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  UndoManager
//
//  Created by Eugene Buleyko on 01.08.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Eugene Buleyko. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

enum color {kWhite = 0, kRed, kOrange, kYellow, kGreen, kCyan, kBlue, kMagenta};

@interface ViewController () {
    enum color kColor;
    NSArray * colorArr;
    NSUndoManager * undoManager;
}

- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)redo:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize buttonRedo, buttonUndo;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    kColor = kWhite;
    colorArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor whiteColor], [UIColor redColor], [UIColor orangeColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor blueColor], [UIColor magentaColor], nil];
    undoManager = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
    undoManager.levelsOfUndo = 9;

    NSNotificationCenter * nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidUndo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification object:self.undoManager];
    [nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(undoManagerDidRedo:) name:NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification object:self.undoManager];

    [self setcolor:kColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender {

    kColor ++;

    if (kColor > kMagenta) {
        kColor = kWhite;
    }
    [self setcolor:kColor];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];

}
-(void) setcolor:(enum color) color{

//    if ([self.view backgroundColor] == colorArr[color]) {
//       NSLog(@"==");
//        
//    } else {
//        NSLog(@"!=");
//    }

    kColor = color;

    [[undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] setcolor:kColor];
    //[undoManager setActionname:@"Add"];
};


- (IBAction)undo:(id)sender {
    [undoManager undo];
}

- (IBAction)redo:(id)sender {
    [undoManager redo];
}

#pragma mark - Undo support

- (void)undoManagerDidUndo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];

    if (![undoManager canUndo]) self.buttonUndo.enabled = NO;
    if ([undoManager canRedo]) self.buttonRedo.enabled = YES;

}

- (void)undoManagerDidRedo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:colorArr[kColor]];

    if (![undoManager canRedo]) self.buttonRedo.enabled = NO;
    if ([undoManager canUndo]) self.buttonUndo.enabled = YES;
}


@end
```

Comment: maybe a few words about what have you added/modified would help.